Unable to pair logitech keyboard
Ubuntu 22.04(dual boot with Windows 10). Keyboard - logitech k380. The keyboard works fine in windows. But in ubuntu nothing happens when I try to connect it through default gnome gui. Then I tried many times through terminal(tried several bluez versions):
bluetoothctl
power on
agent on
default-agent
scan on
trust <Keyboard MAC>
pair <Keyboard MAC>

But everytime there is "failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled" instead of pairing key.
I tried blueman which also fails to pair.

Did this keyboard happen to come with a small device you plug into USB?

@David No. The keyboard works fine in windows on the same machine(dual boot). Before trying to pair with linux I removed the keyboard from windows

Please edit the question and add that it is a dual boot system. That can affect possible answers.

You will need to follow directions from https://gist.github.com/madkoding/f3cfd3742546d5c99131fd19ca267fd4

@Jeremy31 The keyboard cannot be pair with linux at all. I connected wireless headphones to both windows and linux(like in your manual). And it seems that problem only with linux, not dual boot.

Bluetooth Troubleshooting with Logitech K380 Keyboard on Pop!_OS 22.04
1. Install Solaar
sudo apt install solaar
2. Pairing via Terminal

Open bluetoothctl:
bluetoothctl

Start scanning for devices:
[bluetooth]# scan on
Note the address of the K380 keyboard (example: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx).

Stop scanning:
[bluetooth]# scan off

Mark the device as trusted:
[bluetooth]# trust xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Pair the keyboard:
[bluetooth]# pair xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Enter the PIN displayed in the terminal on the K380 keyboard and press Enter.


3. Configure via Solaar
After pairing, open Solaar to manage the keyboard.
Note: The issue was resolved after installing Solaar and pairing the keyboard.
